# Recursively Upload Large Files Via PNP-Powershell to Sharepoint Online Using Large Chunks

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

I have some files that I need to keep in sync with my SharePoint Document Library. The problem is some of the files are over the 250mb limit the code I currently have works but only for files under that 250mb limit. I cannot figure out how to upload the same recursive files I need to SharePoint using the same code and large chunks? It seems that what I need to integrate is option 3 of this page -> [LARGE FILE HANDLING - OPTION 3 (StartUpload, ContinueUpload and FinishUpload)](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP/tree/dev/Samples/Core.LargeFileUpload#large-file-handling---option-3-startupload-continueupload-and-finishupload) also it seems that `if (Test-Path($topSPOFolder+"\"+$aFileName.FullName))` is not checking the target directory if a file exists to skip and move on. Any help is always appreciated.

```
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString "test123" -AsPlainText -Force
$username = "abc@def.com"
$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($username, $password)
$makeUrl ="https://helloworld.sharepoint.com/sites/helloworld"
$sourcePath = "\\1.2.3.4\e$\MSI\packages\*\*.msi";
$topSPOFolder = "Shared Documents\packages\test";
# install pnp powershell..?
#Install-Module SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline
# connect to spo online
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $makeUrl -Credentials $cred
$fileNames = Get-ChildItem -Path $sourcePath -Recurse ;
foreach($aFileName in $fileNames)
{
if($aFileName.GetType().Name -ne "DirectoryInfo") 
   {
    if (Test-Path($topSPOFolder+"\"+$aFileName.FullName)) 
    {
        Write-Host 'Skipping file, already downloaded' -ForegroundColor Yellow
        return
    } else {
      $fn=$topSPOFolder;
      Add-PnPFile -Path $aFileName.FullName -Folder $fn;
      $fn=$null
    }
   }
}
```